# TypeError: products.map is not a function (everything was perfect from the beginning)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mern, array.prototype.map

---

Suddenly getting TypeError: products.map is not a function on  Homescreen.js:22 (below is the code on homescreen.js) everything used to work properly without having the typo. I tried fixing but no avail. Need help! The code is below. Who can help?

---

```
enter code here
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Product from '../components/Product';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';

 export default function HomeScreen() {

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
const { loading, error, products } = productList;

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());
}, [dispatch]);

return ( 
        <div> 
            {loading ? (<LoadingBox />) : 
            error ? (<MessageBox variant = "danger" > { error } </MessageBox>) :
            (<div>
                <div className="row center">
                        { products.map((product) => (
                        <Product key={product._id} product={product}></Product>
                        ))};
                </div>
            </div>)}
        </div>
);
};
```

---

the code from import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';

---

```
 export const listProducts = () => async(dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
   });
   try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/products');
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
   } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
  };
```

Comment: export const listProducts = () => async(dispatch) => { dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, }); try { const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/products'); dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data }); } catch (error) { dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message }); } }; had to change this code to: dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data.payload }); }

Answer (score 0):

Somehow products is undefined, check if products is initialised before mapping the object.

Check bellow :

ps: Do not forget that `map` function is only available for Array Object, products must be an array.

```html
(<div>
        <div className="row center">
                {products && products.map((product) => (
                <Product key={product._id} product={product}></Product>
                ))};
        </div>
</div>)
```

Comment: Then `products` is not an array

Comment: Edit your question with the code where you initialise `products`, I'll update my answer in consequence @hamzymachakala

Comment: updated... but my problem is products.map is not a function (everything was perfect from the beginning) suddenly i keep getting this error. calling products from backend.

Comment: Did you try `products.payload.map` ? @hamzymachakala

Comment: export const listProducts = () => async(dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
   });
   try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/products');
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
   } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
  }; had to change this code to:  
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data.payload });
   }